# Select2 tags not working properly when dynamically appending html

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

[image]

Im using select2 in a form in which rows are appended using jquery, but as seen in the picture, when i append a new row although select2 is working just fine but its width is not adjusted properly. I know this issue might be related to re initialising select2 plugin but somehow im out able to figure it out.

```
    $("#dynamicTable").append(`
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="option">Option${i}</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="key${i}" id="" class="form-control key">
                            <option value="size">Size</option>
                            <option value="color">Color</option>
                            <option value="material">Material</option>
                            <option value="style">Style</option>
                            <option value="title">Title</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><select class="form-control value" id="arr${i}" multiple="multiple" name="value${i}[]"></select></td>

                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr" id="${i}">Remove</button></td>

                </tr>
                `);

                $(".value").select2({
                    tags: true,
                    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
                });
```

Here is the code, when we append a row, a select tag having class of .value is appended into the html.

Comment: could you please share the code that does so ? ex: the code that appends new rows and for sure the select2 initialization (including the `select` element)

Comment: Yes i edited my question now by adding the code.

Comment: You are not appending any option inside your `.value` select box ?